# Java APIs to access Office 365 cloud

Tags: cloud, office365

Is there a way to access Office365 cloud applications using Java API. I understand this is a very broad question. But I am looking for a generic guideline here.

Answer (score 2):

- The Office365 REST API's can give you access to mail, calendar, contacts, files
  etc. See documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn605892(v=office.15).aspx).

  - There is also an Android SDK you can use [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Android).

Comment: Thanks. My question is, are those APIS in Java. I have seen C# and JavaScript APIs. But not Java.

Comment: @Sumod we'll support Java very soon.

Comment: @Sumod within a month. We're working on it. Maybe less.

Comment: @Zenil https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Java . We'll try to release this week.

Comment: Before asking, we will sync with jcenter first, but then we'll try to sync with sonatype later. Please use the https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Java/issues if something is not correct

Comment: @Markust Does ews-java-api support microsoft office 365 ?

Comment: @Zenil Outlook Office 365 uses an OData based REST API and our SDKs target that. From my understanding EWS uses a different API, a SOAP based one. Makes sense?